# MSSQL Query JSON displays Null value

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table `PublicRelations` with a column called `Students` in a SQL Server database called `Subjects`.

```
[
    { "Label": "Name",     "ColumnValue": "Trudie" },      
    { "Label": "Class",    "ColumnValue": "PublicRelations" },      
    { "Label": "Room",     "ColumnValue": "8049" },      
    { "Label": "HttpPath", "ColumnValue": "https://www.google.com/" }
]
```

I only get `NULL` when I run the below query using the `Json_value`. I'd like to get it to display the value from the array.  I believe this may have to do with the 4000 character limit?

```sql
SELECT      [StuduentID], 
            [Students],
            --JSON_VALUE([Students],'$.ColumnValue') AS Name --Only returns NULL
FROM        [Subjects].[dbo].[PublicRelations] c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.Students)
  WITH (    Name int '$.Name',
            Value nvarchar(255) '$.ColmunValue'
  ) AS      jsonValues
WHERE       jsonValues.ColumnValue = 'Trudie'
```

The query works and I can find what I need, but again, I only get `NULL` when I want to display that part of the JSON column in my results.

Comment: have you tried it with correct spelling of `ColmunValue`?

Comment: Yes on original; I retyped it all over in a hurry to practice typing; as stated that works;  the issue I want to resolve is how to  display the individual values from the json array in my tsql results

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Apart from the misspelling you also seem to be selecting a property that does not exist. The JSON only has 2 properties and neither of them are called Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong and you has the following issues (as @MartinSmith already mentioned):

- Syntax error - `'$.ColmunValue'` should be `'$.ColumnValue'`.
- Wrong schema definition (the `WITH` clause) - I can't see `Name` key in the input JSON.
- Wrong use of [JSON_VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - this function extracts scalar value from a JSON string, so `JSON_VALUE([Students],'$.ColumnValue')` returns `NULL` with this JSON input in `lax` mode.

You may try with the following statement (based on the statement in the question):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PublicRelations (
   StudentID int,
   Students nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO PublicRelations (StudentID, Students) 
VALUES (1, N'[
    { "Label": "Name",     "ColumnValue": "Trudie" },      
    { "Label": "Class",    "ColumnValue": "PublicRelations" },      
    { "Label": "Room",     "ColumnValue": "8049" },      
    { "Label": "HttpPath", "ColumnValue": "https://www.google.com/" }
]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT p.StudentID, j.*
FROM [PublicRelations] p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.Students) WITH (
   Name nvarchar(50) '$.Label',
   Value nvarchar(255) '$.ColumnValue'
) j
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM OPENJSON(p.Students) WITH (Value nvarchar(255) '$.ColumnValue')
   WHERE Value = N'Trudie'
) AND (j.Name IN ('Name', 'Class', 'Room'))
```

Result:

```
StudentID   Name     Value
1           Name     Trudie
1           Class    PublicRelations
1           Room     8049
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to  query on name but also show the values;  in my sample there are 4 but there are a total of over 25 Keys i.e. firstname lastname etc... So in your sample, If search Trudy, I see:  StudentID = 1; Name = Name; Value = Trudie, I want to Also add Room as a results display column  but not ALL the columns

Comment: @user3191894 I understand, you need an appropriate `WHERE` clause. The answer is updated. Thanks.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank You!